# Terraform ssl for ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, terraform

With in me listener code I have the line

```
ssl_certificate_id = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:321633319430:certificate/846353d3-39cc-47b4-ac02-cc9c380f7fd3"
```

Which is the ARN copied from the cert manager page in AWS.

but when i try to apply i get

```
invalid or unknown key: ssl_certificate_id
```

Can anyone tell me why this is? this is a AWS cert I am trying to apply.

cheers

Comment: Can you show more of your terraform ALB block?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a classic ELB or an ALB (also known as elbv2) ?

Exactly at the error message says, `ssl_certificate_id` isn't a valid argument for resource [aws_alb](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/alb.html).

You add ssl certificates to an [aws_alb_listener](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/alb_listener.html) instead using the `certificate_arn` argument.